# Using super() on Python2.x classes in Django

Tags: python, django, class, super

My models.py looks like this :

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
    date_prescribed = models.DateTimeField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)  
    pharmacy = models.ForeignKey(Pharmacy)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)  
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Pharmacy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    status = models.CharField()
```

In my views,I want the count of prescriptions grouped by month.I am using Django rest framework.My views.py is as follows:

```
class PrescriptionTrendListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Prescription.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LineGraphSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        end_date = timezone.now()
        start_date = end_date - relativedelta(months=6)
        truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_prescribed')
        qs = super().get_queryset.extra(select={'month': truncate_date})
        return qs.filter(date_prescribed__range=(start_date, end_date)
        ).annotate(pk_count=Count('pk')).order_by('month')


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        graph_data = self.get_queryset().values('pk_count', 'month')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=graph_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

However,the error I get when I run this is :
[image]
[image]

I am assuming this has something to do with new style classes in Python 3.0.But that is all i know.Any help on how to fix this on 2.x ?

Comment: Can you post full stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `super()` call in `get_queryset` is missing the `type` and `self` arguments.

```
class PrescriptionTrendListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Prescription.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LineGraphSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        end_date = timezone.now()
        start_date = end_date - relativedelta(months=6)
        truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'date_prescribed')
        # Bug was here
        qs = super(PrescriptionTrendListView, self).get_queryset.extra(select={'month': truncate_date})
        return qs.filter(date_prescribed__range=(start_date, end_date)
        ).annotate(pk_count=Count('pk')).order_by('month')


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        graph_data = self.get_queryset().values('pk_count', 'month')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=graph_data, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, syntax for `super` is this:

```
class MyClass(Base):
    def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really stupid but I suspect it's because you're referencing Doctor and Pharmacy before you declare them. Try this instead:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)  
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Pharmacy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    status = models.CharField()
class Prescription(models.Model):
    date_prescribed = models.DateTimeField()
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)  
    pharmacy = models.ForeignKey(Pharmacy)
```

I looked at some of my old Django on Python 2.x and your models look fine, just that seems to be an issue maybe(?)